# When new tokens are get in Keycloak, previous sessions are not closed

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak-services

A new session is created every time I get tokens from Keycloak. Every time I get a token, I want the previous sessions to be closed. I have not seen such a service on the Keycloak side. What method can be developed for this?

**Keycloak version:** 19.0.0

I get the token in this way;

**URL:**
http://keycloak_url/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token

**body**

```
username:{username}
password:{password}
client_id:{client}
grant_type:password
```

Comment: Tokens are not sessions, a token must time out on its own.

Comment: I didn't say tokens are sessions.every time I receive a token, a client session occurs for the corresponding user.

Comment: @kernel Are you saying, that your Spring Boot application is opening a HTTP session on Keycloak's server every time your Spring Boot application is getting a new token? I wouldn't expect it, but what's the problem?

Comment: BTW: `spring-security-oauth2` is end of life since 2022. You should upgrade your application to Spring Security 5/6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding the "User Session count limiter" step to the "direct grant" flow on the authentication page in the Keycloak interface.

[image]